# How to parse the expression "таких, как я, будет все больше и больше"

Tags: грамматика

> Если никто им не даст отпор, **таких, как я, будет все больше и больше**.

In parsing this part, I'm not sure:

- what is the (singular) subject of this main clause. Is it "больше и больше"?
- why "таких" is in the genitive. Is it because "больше и больше + (genitive)" works just like "много  + (genitive)"?
- what is the function of "таких". Is it an animate substantive with the meaning of "such people"?
- if "все" serves as an adverb with the meaning of "always".

To facilitate understanding, can I interpret the construction as:

> все больше и больше {(+genitive) таких} будет {(as a predicate) как я}.
>
> == "(always) more and more (of) people will be/become/end up like me."

Or more naturally:

> == "If no one opposes them, more and more people will go through {such things that //} what I have gone through."

Comment: Without the specific context it is not possible to nail what specific aspect of "like me" is referred to. Maybe, like in your latter example", it is indeed just "victims of" and nothing more. Calling to the sense of justice and sympathy. Or it may be "crippled like me", meaning the society would have more and more burden of supporting those crippled due to accepting that some bullying. However by default I would suppose "ones being hurt and dreaming of revenge". And the whole situation implied to be like a sealed can forgotten on fire, with internal pressure evergrowing until a loud bang.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s compare:

Будет много фруктов. — There will be lots of fruit.

Будет больше фруктов. — There will be more fruit.

Будет всё больше и больше фруктов. — The amount of fruit will be constantly increasing day after day. (“больше и больше” is quite similar to “more and more” and can be used without “всё”, which just adds a bit of emphasis on the trend)

Будет всё больше и больше таких фруктов, как в Турции. — There will be more and more fruit of the kind they have in Turkey.

Будет всё больше и больше таких [людей], как я. — There will be more and more people like me.

Your final translation is correct.

Comment: Hi. When "таких" or "такиe" means "people", does the word still carry the *type-specifying* "**such** (people)" sense? That is, "people **like this/that**"? Or is it more general like "**those** (who/like ...) / **people**" in English?

Comment: @Alone-zee “такие, как [некоторые другие люди]” can only refer to people similar in some regard to some other people. “Таким, как он, здесь не рады” — “Those who are like him are not welcome here”. If you want to refer to some quality, use “те, кто [проявляют некоторую особенность]”. “Тем, кто мусорит, здесь не рады” — “Those who litter are not welcome here”.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the (singular) subject of this main clause. Is it "больше и больше"?

It's the same third person singular like `идёт дождь` or `у меня новая машина`

> why "таких" is in the genitive. Is it because "больше и больше + (genitive)" works just like "много + (genitive)"?

That's right

> what is the function of "таких". Is it an animate substantive with the meaning of "such people"?

That's right, `больше чего` means "more **of** what" so it's genitive.

> if "все" serves as an adverb with the meaning of "always".

Not sure about that, best wait for a native

Comment: About всё/always. In my (not native) grasping of English, always refers to the situation, rather than process. So, "It is always raining here". The rain keeps falling, but it does not change the situation, there is no flood - drops merge into streams, streams merge into rivers, and nothing big changes. But in this specific phrase it is implied that the situation WILL change. It is like a pressure is growing in a can forgotten on fire, until the vessel gives way and the pressure releases in an explosion.

Comment: So, i'd convey "всё" here along "...number of people like me would **continuously/persistently/endlessly** grow higher and higher". Though perhaps it would not be the best choice of English word here. Roman above conveys "всё" with "**constantly**" in his fruits-related example. Perhaps it would had been the most natural choice of the word.

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing the answers @Wilson and @Roman Odaisky gave. "Всё" if used with an adverb serves as the mean of amplification or continuity. Doesn't really change the meaning of the adverb itself.

Here, however, "всё" is used redundantly (maybe emotionally): "больше и больше" -- "more and more [from day to day, minute to minute, etc.] "; 
"всё больше и больше" -- "more and more [from day to day, minute to minute, etc.]" (in this context!).

Alternatively: "будет больше" -- "(there) will be more"; "будет всё больше" -- "(there) will be more [from day to day, ...]".

Comment: Maybe "всё" in "всё больше и больше" has a similar, if not the same, function as  "всё" in "всё еше"?

Comment: @Alone-zee: I think it's contextual only. The "больше и больше" expression sort of implies the presence of "всё". "Ещё" and "всё ещё" have such equivalence only in the case when "ещё" means "yet".